# Oracle Error : System.data.oracleclient requires oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater

Tags: oracle11g

I am working in C#.Net Application. I had hosted my application in IIS in Server. That server contains Oracle 11g version ( 64 Bit ). The Server is also 64 Bit Machine. But while running my application i am getting the error as

> system.data.oracleclient requires oracle client software version
>   8.1.7 or greater

Whether i need to install oracle client version in that server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above issue had been fixed.

Solution : The "Authenticated Users" in Oracle Home folder should give Read and Write Permissions and the System should be " RESTARTED ".